# How can I save user input values?

Tags: python, python-3.8

I have to make a model of the database of a book store for my high school project. 
There's the function to enter the info a new book, but I want it to remain even after killing the the program. Currently, I've just entered a few books in the code itself so that it won't be empty when run.

I'm pretty much done with it but I just wanna know how I can save user input data for later.

```
books={1001:['Inferno','Dan Brown','Anchor Books','Thriller',42.00,70],
       1002:['As You Like It','William Shakespear','Penguin Publications','Classics',20.00,54],
       1003:['The Kite Runner','Khaled Hosseini','Bloomsbury Publcations','Drama',30.00,70],
       1004:['A Thousand Splendid Suns','Khaled Hosseini','Bloomsbury Publications','Fiction',35.00,70],
       1005:['The Girl on The Train','Paula Hawkins','Riverhead Books','Thriller',28.00,100],
       1006:['The Alchemist','Paulo Coelho','Rupa Books','Drama',25.00,50]}
while True:
    print ('ID    |   Name')
    [print(key,' | ',books[key][0]) for key in books.keys()]
    print (

'''

MAIN MENU:-
1. Add new book details
2. Modify data of a specific book
3. Delete all data of a book
4. View all data of a book
***********************************
5. Check Availability
6. Sales
7. Exit

''')

    cho=int(input('Enter your choice(1-7):'))
    if cho==1:
        book_id=int(input('Enter the book id:'))
        b_name=input('Enter the book name:-')
        a_name=input('Enter the authors name:')
        p_name=input('Enter name of publication:')
        genre=input('Enter the genre of the book:')
        price=float(input('Enter the price of the book (with decimal place):'))
        no_copy=int(input('Enter no of copies available:'))
        books[book_id]=[b_name,a_name,p_name,genre,price,no_copy]
    elif cho==2:

        book_id=int(input('Enter book id:'))
        print (books[book_id])
        print('''0. Book name
1. Author's name
2. Publisher
3. Genre
4. Price
5. No of copies''')
        index=int(input('Enter index of data to be changed:'))
        if index>=0 and index<=3:
            new_val=input('Enter the modified value:')
        elif index==4:
            new_val=float(input('Enter the modified value (with decimal place):'))
        elif index==5:
            new_val=int(input('Enter the modified value:'))
        books[book_id][index]=new_val
    elif cho==3:
         book_id=int(input('Enter book id of book to be deleted:'))
         print ('Book', book_id, 'data deleted')
         del books[book_id]
    elif cho==4:
        book_id=int(input('Enter the book id:'))
        print(books[book_id])
    elif cho==5:
        book_id=int(input('Enter book id of book to check availability:'))
        print ('''
''', books[book_id][5], 'copies are currently in stock')
    elif cho==6:
        book_id=int(input('Enter book id of book to buy:'))
        nos=int(input('Number of copies to buy'))
        books[book_id][5]=books[book_id][5]-nos
        print (nos,'copies of books purchased')
    elif cho==7:
        break
```

I'm sorry if the code hurts to look at, I'm extremely new to Python. Also if you have any suggestions to make it better, that would be awesome.

Comment: There are a number of *built-ins*:  [Data Persistance](https://docs.python.org/3/library/persistence.html). `pickle` would probably suffice.

Answer (score 1):

You can  write the input to a file (preferrably csv file for your case). [CSV File I/O Link](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-read-and-write-csv-files-in-python--cms-29907)

Answer (score 1):

you could save / load variable to file.

An option is "[hickle](https://pypi.org/project/hickle/)"

**To install:**

```
pip install hickle
```

**Use:**

```
import hickle as hkl

# write variables to filename [a,b,c can be of any size]
hkl.dump([a,b,c], filename)

# load variables from filename
a,b,c = hkl.load(filename)
```

**Modified your code:**

```
import hickle as hkl

filename='books.file'
books ={}

try:
    books = hkl.load(filename)
except IOError:
    print("File not exists")


while True:
    print ('ID    |   Name')
    [print(key,' | ',books[key][0]) for key in books.keys()]
    print (

'''

MAIN MENU:-
1. Add new book details
2. Modify data of a specific book
3. Delete all data of a book
4. View all data of a book
***********************************
5. Check Availability
6. Sales
7. Exit

''')

    cho=int(input('Enter your choice(1-7):'))
    if cho==1:
        book_id=int(input('Enter the book id:'))
        b_name=input('Enter the book name:-')
        a_name=input('Enter the authors name:')
        p_name=input('Enter name of publication:')
        genre=input('Enter the genre of the book:')
        price=float(input('Enter the price of the book (with decimal place):'))
        no_copy=int(input('Enter no of copies available:'))
        books[book_id]=[b_name,a_name,p_name,genre,price,no_copy]
        hkl.dump(books, filename)
    elif cho==2:

        book_id=int(input('Enter book id:'))
        print (books[book_id])
        print('''0. Book name
1. Author's name
2. Publisher
3. Genre
4. Price
5. No of copies''')
        index=int(input('Enter index of data to be changed:'))
        if index>=0 and index<=3:
            new_val=input('Enter the modified value:')
        elif index==4:
            new_val=float(input('Enter the modified value (with decimal place):'))
        elif index==5:
            new_val=int(input('Enter the modified value:'))
        books[book_id][index]=new_val
    elif cho==3:
         book_id=int(input('Enter book id of book to be deleted:'))
         print ('Book', book_id, 'data deleted')
         del books[book_id]
    elif cho==4:
        book_id=int(input('Enter the book id:'))
        print(books[book_id])
    elif cho==5:
        book_id=int(input('Enter book id of book to check availability:'))
        print ('''
''', books[book_id][5], 'copies are currently in stock')
    elif cho==6:
        book_id=int(input('Enter book id of book to buy:'))
        nos=int(input('Number of copies to buy'))
        books[book_id][5]=books[book_id][5]-nos
        print (nos,'copies of books purchased')
    elif cho==7:
        break
```

Comment: I tried running the code but it said that a module named hickle doesn't exist

Comment: Tried with pickle, works as equal hickle. https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html

Answer (score 1):

use csv file to store all data.

```
import csv   
if cho==1:
        book_id=int(input('Enter the book id:'))
        b_name=input('Enter the book name:-')
        a_name=input('Enter the authors name:')
        p_name=input('Enter name of publication:')
        genre=input('Enter the genre of the book:')
        price=float(input('Enter the price of the book (with decimal place):'))
        no_copy=int(input('Enter no of copies available:'))
        books[book_id]=[b_name,a_name,p_name,genre,price,no_copy]
for book in books:
    with open('books.csv', 'a') as bks:
        writer = csv.writer(bks)
        writer.writerow(book)
```

Comment: `books` is a dictionary - in your for loop `book` would be the key only.

Comment: ``` for keys,value in books.items():
    with open('books.csv', 'a') as bks:
        writer = csv.writer(bks)
        writer.writerow(value)```

Answer (score 1):

There is a couple of ways to go about this:

1. Connect program to a database. I would say that the most appropriate in this case would be [SQLite](https://www.codecademy.com/articles/what-is-sqlite).
2. Save your data locally to a file. I would suggest using [pandas](https://towardsdatascience.com/a-quick-introduction-to-the-pandas-python-library-f1b678f34673) to turn data to a data frame and manipulate it. After you can save the data frame to a [CSV](https://realpython.com/python-csv/). Here are the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/index.html) for pandas.

As far as improving your code, I would suggest breaking it up into [functions](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_functions.asp). It will be easier to debug and understand. Good luck with your project!